# Is there a name for a place that sells nuts?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for a store that mainly sells nuts and seeds? Like this one:

[image: Nut shop]

Comment: Maybe a _nuthouse_?

Comment: @Cascabel "Nuthouse: a home or hospital for people with mental illnesses."

Comment: @Laurel It was tongue-in-cheek. Guess I shoulda put one of those smilies. More seriously however, there is _nuttery_, which is "a place to store nuts".

Comment: I think it's just called a nut shop. That actual business is called "The Nut Shop" lol

Comment: I think that *nuttery* referes to a mental hospital.  [Online Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199543700.001.0001/acref-9780199543700-e-3220?rskey=G7iLqu&result=3220).

Comment: If it also sold *bolts* I would call it a *hardware* store. (Just kidding). :-)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 That´s from the slang dictionary.  Collins and MW have _nuttery_  as "a grove of nut trees or a place to store nuts."

Comment: @Laurel Hence Cascabel's not using an 'answer'.

Comment: There is actually a business in my local area called "The Nut House" that sells nuts and nut butters, in addition to candies.

Comment: *nut bar*?...........

Comment: If I owned that shop, I guarantee it would be called "The Blind Squirrel."

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a widely recognized term like *butcher* or *pharmacy*, but *nut shop* would describe the store and *nut seller* the shopkeeper. The Oxford English Dictionary has the latter listed under "[nut, n.1 and adj.2,](https://oed.com/view/Entry/129285)" referring to the person (the monger) selling the nuts:

> nut seller  n.
>
> 1648   H. Hexham Groot Woorden-boeck   Een note-menger, a Nut-seller.
>
> 1851   H. Mayhew London Labour I. 201/1   These almond nut-sellers
> are, for the most part, itinerant.
>
> 1990   Chicago Tribune (Nexis) 25 June (Business section) 5   The
> tentmakers share a street, as do the nut sellers, the gold merchants,
> and those selling silk or coffee or discount underwear.

*Nut shop* does not have a similar entry, but the same pattern exists: the nut shop is where nuts are sold. Some results also point to its use:

- the above image and many others can be found in [Alamy under "nut shop,"](https://www.alamy.com/search.html?pn=1&ps=100&qt=nut%20shop&qt_raw=nut%20shop)
- Now-closed New York City nut shop "We Are Nuts About Nuts" was called a "nut shop" by both an [Eater New York article](https://ny.eater.com/2017/7/12/15960334/sp-nuts-and-candy-tribeca-closing) ("by the time the **nut shop** opened, the area had a sexy, new TriBeCa moniker") and interviewee David Dyssegaard Kallick: "I like that **nut shop**. I’m sorry to see it going. There’s some loss to the character of the neighborhood without it."
- The Chicago Tribune reported on another place opening last year: "[Octogenarian and her daughter open **nut shop** in Highland Park amid pandemic](https://www.chicagotribune.com/suburbs/highland-park/ct-hpn-sallys-nuts-snack-shop-tl-1217-20201212-2aifk422oncspo7uwpoqtsoiyy-story.html)." In the article, one of the founders says: “But I think that people are really looking for something positive and even if it’s just this tiny little **nut shop**, they just want something to feel good about.”

Answer (score 2):

The word **nuttery** is [defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuttery) as:

> :  a place where nut trees grow; also :  a place for storing nuts.

So, a "store" for nuts is a nuttery.

Comment: Now, in the words of Shakespeare, "Get thee to a nuttery, go!"

Comment: You're erroneously using amphiboly. A store as a storage place is not at the same thing as a store where things are sold.

Comment: @Mitch you have to store the nuts in order to sell them don't you?

Comment: I think it's kind of a false dichotomy.  If you look up the word "store" in M-W it's defined as "a business establishment where usually diversified goods are kept for retail sale."  It specifically says where goods are kept.  That's exactly what the OP is referring to.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that there is quite some degree of difference in the use of 'store' between British and American English. Almost any sales outlet can be a store in American, while in British 'shop' is the usual word, with 'store' typically being reserved for very large shops, especially warehouse-like one such as DIY stores. Consequently, the primary meaning of 'store' when encountered out of context would be 'shop' for an American but probably the warehouse meaning for a Brit.

Answer (score 0):

"Roastery"
"Nuts & Coffee Roastery"
Where brewed coffee is **not** served, it is only for selling grounded or whole grains coffee beans and roasted or raw nuts

Comment: I've only hears the word "roastery" used for a place that roasts coffee beans, not nuts. Using it for a nut shop would be like using "brewery" for a shop that brews coffee and tea — massively misleading.